# Instantiate variable in one if-clause and use it in another if-clause

Tags: java, syntax, ide

I have the following code example:

```
 boolean test=(0.5>Math.random());

    if (!test) {
        int testVariable=5;
    }

    if (test){
        //do this
    } else {
        testVariable+=5;
    }
```

I get the "testVariable cannot be resolved to a variable" error, even though if testVariable is not initialized, the else branch from the second if will not be executed. This happens in Eclipse and NetBeans IDEs. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Read up on scope rules in Java. Your text book and your favourite search engine should both be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Now your `testVariable` is in a scope of `if`, it's not visible anywhere else. You need to do this before your if:

`int testVariable = 0`

Then ofcourse in your `if` you need to remove `int`, because variable was already declared.

[Read about variable scopes here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

Answer (score 2):

Declare it outside the if loop. Its scope is limited to the if , which is why its not visible outside the if.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `testVariable` this variable inside of `if` that's why `testVariable` variable only available within this `if block` and you can,t use it out side of `if`.

If want to access out side of if then declare this variable outside of if.

For example :

```
int testVariable = 0;
boolean test=(0.5>Math.random());

if (!test) {
    testVariable=5;
}

if (test){
    //do this
} else {
    testVariable+=5;
}
```

Comment: In situations like this where the initial value is not supposed to be used ever I sometimes initialize `testVariable` to some crazy value, like -4778. I hope this will make it easier to detect in case the initial value somehow gets used where it should not.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:-

```
 boolean test=(0.5>Math.random());

    if (!test) { // 1st if
        int testVariable=5;
    }

    if (test){ // 2nd if
        //do this
    } else {
        testVariable+=5;
    }
```

You have declared the variable inside if case. Now, as per java scoping the scope of that variable lies within the closing curly braces only. So, as soon as the program of execution goes beyond the closing curly braces, that variable is out of scope and is not available to be used anymore.

You should probably declare the variable outside of first if case if you want to use this in later cases as well. Like:-

```
int testVariable = 0;
 boolean test=(0.5>Math.random());

    if (!test) {
        testVariable=5;
    }

    if (test){
        //do this
    } else {
        testVariable+=5;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

- If a variable is declared within a block then it is accessible only
  within the block.
- So declare the variable outside the block locally. So that you can assign
  values to the variable within the blocks too.

Your code should be modified to,

```
boolean test=(0.5>Math.random());
int testVariable=0;
if (!test) {
    testVariable=5;
}
if (test){
    //do this
}
else {
    testVariable+=5;
 }
```